# Get Product Perl and cUrl

Tags: xml, json, perl, curl, bigcommerce

I am using perl and cURL to connect to BigCommerce.

I am getting orders successfully, I am getting the list of items in the order successfully. But that does not return detailed product info (like the name of it!) so I need to make another call.

I am making the call and it is successful, but it is returning XML where the docs say it will return json.

I could code for the XML, but I am not sure I should be getting XML

Here is the call

```
/usr/bin/curl --request GET -u "xxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         https://store-ospzkdl.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/76
```

Docs
Get a Product

Gets a product.

```
OAuth
Basic Auth
```

GET /api/v2/products/{id}

Response

Example JSON returned in the response:

{
  "id": 32,
  "keyword_filter": null,
etc

This is my first day with the API. Any help Appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like something that you'll have to ask them.  Where's the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs say](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/req-headers) you will receive either an XML or a JSON response based on the HTTP `Accept` header.

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' ...
```

Comment: @MikeCarvilleGleTech - You should accept the answer if it helped you out! Marking it as accepted indicates to future users having the same problem, that this is a valid solution. Besides that, you will earn a new shiny Scholar badge :)

Comment: thank you, I have accepted it. I had tried to upvote it but it would not let me.